# Finding the last zero's index in an array

Tags: java

I wrote the following code for finding the last zero index in an array:

```
public class Stack {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a=new int[5];
        a[0]=1;
        a[1]=0;
        a[2]=90;
        a[3]=0;
        a[4]=4;
        findLast(a);
    }
    public static int findLast(int[] x){
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
         if(x[i]==0){
             System.out.println(i);             
         }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
1
3
```

What I really want is the index 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Start at the end of the array (i.e. `i=x.length-1`)
- Decrement `i` rather than incrementing (i.e. use `i--`)
- Stop as soon as you reach zero (i.e. add `break` after `println`).
- Make your stopping condition such that the loop processes element at index zero.

Comment: This will have the least time complexity. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 3):

Just reverse the loop going from `x.length-1` to `0` and return the index on first match:

```
public static int findLast(int[] x) {
    for (int i=x.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (x[i] == 0) {
            // match found, return index
            return i;
        }
    }
    // no match found, return invalid index
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Stack {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a=new int[5];
        a[0]=1;
        a[1]=0;
        a[2]=90;
        a[3]=0;
        a[4]=4;
        findLast(a);
    }
    public static void findLast(int[] x){
        for(int i=x.length()-1;i>0;i++){
        if(x[i]==0){
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your constraint is to traverse the array from the start, Store the index as and when you see `0` into a variable and as you complete the loop just print the variable

```
int lastindex;
for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
         if(x[i]==0){
             lastindex=i;
}
System.out.println(lastindex);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int lastZero(int[] x){
        int temp=0;
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
         if(x[i]==0){
             temp=i;
         }
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
        return 0;
    }
```

This would give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the END of the array and decrement through. Should we never find a zero, this returns -1, which is always outside of the index. This is interpreted by you

```
public class Stack {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a=new int[5];
    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=0;
    a[2]=90;
    a[3]=0;
    a[4]=4;
    findLast(a);
}
public static int findLast(int[] x){
    for(int i=x.length-1;i>=0;i--){
     if(x[i]==0){
         return i;             
     }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}